# CSS goes away after htaccess change

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Sorry for the bad English or the grammar mistakes in this post.

I'm having trouble with making SEO friendly URLs with mod_rewrite. It already worked do make this:

> ra*solutions.nl/blockade?ip=00.00.00.000
>
> ra*solutions.nl/blockade/00.00.00.000

But the problem is that when I visit the second URL, the CSS from my site is gone, my entire site is white. And if I try to click an other URL from my site the link will automaticllyy become ra*solutions.nl/blockade/index

My htaccess code:

```
DirectoryIndex login.php

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

#Blockade.php
RewriteRule ^blockade/(.*)/?$    blockade.php?ip=$1    [NC,L]

#No .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

And what I mean by white:
http://prntscr.com/3e3hqt

Comment: Try adding a `/` before the css. So `css/style.css` would become `/css.style.css`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my CSS wouldn't been seen because the URL would be this:
blockade/css/style.css

Basically to fix this I've used a BASE href to make the problem go away. Thanks to everybody for helping!